# Uart on Atmel Studio SAML21 Xplained with example project?

Tags: uart, atmel

I want to send a variable given by the function at30tse_read_temperature, on the example project of Atmel Studio called "AT30TSE75X_TEMP_SENSO".

I added the usart with some help and ASF wizard, and it's working when I call it with `printf("something")` (I have the output on my PC with Tera Term).

I want to send the variable output of a function.

Here is my code:

```
temp_res = at30tse_read_temperature();
double *temp_result = &temp_res;

//printf("%f", at30tse_read_temperature());
u_char *c_Data = ( u_char* ) &temp_result;
//usart_serial_write_packet(&cdc_uart_module,c_Data,sizeof(temp_result));
usart_serial_write_packet(&cdc_uart_module,c_Data,sizeof(c_Data));
```

I'm totally out... I don't know how to send the variable of a function I called 3 lines above...

I'm pretty sure it's easy, and I made a lot of huge mistakes...Please help me !

It's the example project on atmel studio, with uart added.

Comment: You pass the pointer of the pointer of temp_result. Please give more infos on what’s not working.